Great, there's two of them now
What is the name of the game?










Condensed race
A small amount
____


Hated visitor on bread
Template of a certain shape
____ or _____


Edge of a pizza
Outer layer of Earth
_____


Consume
Turkey noise
______


Key part of Norwegian culture
Internet annoyance
_____


Deep cooling in the refrigerator
Caused by computer bug
______


Intense song ____
Microphone ____
____


A type of meat
Rollercoaster
_____


Gap in sound
Midday nap
____


Outrageous
Lightning
________


Not rotation, but close
Tool used to cut grass
_____


A later stage of clicker games
Status
________


Loosely fixed shape
Adaptable
_________


Share a sung note
Have emotional impact
________



The result should be a phrase with 2 words.

Hint 1:

 Metafirsts.


Is there perhaps a mistake with the formatting?

Apparently. The table is meant to actually work. It works in the preview, at least.

Unfortunately, the rendering requires newlines around the table, but that will only break in the render, not in the preview.

This is what I have so far:
(Thank you to the people in the comments for some answers!)










Condensed race
A small amount
Dash


Hated visitor on bread
Template of a certain shape
Mold or Mould


Edge of a pizza
Outer layer of Earth
Crust


Consume
Turkey noise
Gobble


Key part of Norwegian culture
Internet annoyance
Troll


Deep cooling in the refrigerator
Caused by computer bug
Freeze


Intense song ____
Microphone ____
Hook


A type of meat
Rollercoaster
Jerky/Strip


Gap in sound
Midday nap
Rest


Outrageous
Lightning
Shocking


Not rotation, but close
Tool used to cut grass
Shear


A later stage of clicker games
Status
Prestige


Loosely fixed shape
Adaptable
Malleable


Share a sung note
Have emotional impact
Resonate



P.S.: I think the number of dashes given for each blank answer in the question is the number of letters for that word.

Not rotation, but close, and Tool used to cut grass are rot13(furne); Outrageous and Lightning are probably rot13(fubpxvat); Type of meat and Roller Coaster might be rot13(jvatf); and Gap in sound and Midday nap might be rot13(erfg).

I see, thank you!

Nice partial, but #1 and #8 are wrong.

Changed #1 and Removed #8

All of the ones you have are correct.

#13 is close. (Filler for 15.)

I see. What do you mean by "Filler for 15" btw?
